# Bootstrap grid : No horizontal scroll when all column does not fit in one row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

Why does the column that does not fit in one row goes to the bottom instead of showing a horizontal scrollbar?

```
<div class="container-fluid main-container" style="overflow-x: auto; width:600px">
    <div class="row mx-5">
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 mx-4 mt-12">
            ...column 1 content
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 mx-4 mt-12">
            ...column 2 content
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 mx-4 mt-12">
            ...column 3 content
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 mx-4 mt-12">
            ...column 4 content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Expected Behaviour:**

If the `4 div columns` does not fit in one row, a `horizontal scrollbar` should show.

**Current Outcome:**

The 4th column goes to the bottom of `column 1, column 2, and column 3`

An image of the outcome :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `flex-nowrap` class to achieve your goal.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid main-container" style="overflow-x: auto; width:600px">
    <div class="row mx-5 flex-nowrap">
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 mx-4 mt-12">
            ...column 1 content
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 mx-4 mt-12">
            ...column 2 content
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 mx-4 mt-12">
            ...column 3 content
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 mx-4 mt-12">
            ...column 4 content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

why you using grid to do this?

try using some carousel.
https://flickity.metafizzy.co/options.html#freescroll

bootstrap use percentual grid, you can do it manual like:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  background: red;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.container .content {
  width: 820px;
}

.container .box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.container .box:nth-child(1) {
  background: blue;
}

.container .box:nth-child(2) {
  background: cyan;
}

.container .box:nth-child(3) {
  background: purple;
}

.container .box:nth-child(4) {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="box">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```